# Massage data in a dict with array of json objects (nested data/data in a tree structure) in Python 3.0

Tags: python, arrays, json

I need to store the value of 'Address' in a variable for later use. The 'address' value is deep inside an output from a json.dump.

From what I've gathered over looking through some similar issues is that I need to iterate between each value in order access the ScriptPubKey (dict). Since I am only a few hours in to Python, without much prior knowledge about programming, I'm sure that I'm missing something simple - or completely misunderstand the task at hand.

```py
    for x in response['result']['vout']:
    for y in x:
    print(y)
```

So this is the part of the program I am having issues with:

```py
###Function
def gettranshash(transhashen):
    payload = {
    "method": "getrawtransaction",
    "params": [transhashen],
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json() 
    response = response['result']
    payload = {
    "method": "decoderawtransaction",
    "params": [response],
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json()
    return response

###How I access the function in my program
        transaktionshash = input("write transactionhash for a block: ")
        response = gettranshash(transaktionshash)
        print("Blocket: ", response['result']['hash'])
###Missing the address output :(
        print("Blocket: ", response['result']['vout'])
```

Result from response:

```
{'result': {'txid': 
'4d879b24d65dd418a8e806ed69df7f170022e89666590a7b08e0095009865a5b', 
'hash': 
'4d879b24d65dd418a8e806ed69df7f170022e89666590a7b08e0095009865a5b', 
'version': 1, 'size': 87, 'vsize': 87, 'locktime': 0, 'vin': 
[{'coinbase': '0163', 'sequence': 4294967295}], 'vout': [{'value': 50.0, 
'n': 0, 'scriptPubKey': {'asm': 'OP_DUP OP_HASH160 
071e31b8289aa9d80b970230cb1b8b76466f2ec4 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG', 
'hex': '76a914071e31b8289aa9d80b970230cb1b8b76466f2ec488ac', 'reqSigs': 
1, 'type': 'pubkeyhash', 'addresses': 
['1eduGsrvBJcfyTMij2rYXk9viiVV78PNq']}}]}, 'error': None, 'id': None}
```

---

This is the result from response['result']['vout']:

```
[{'value': 50.0, 'n': 0, 'scriptPubKey': {'asm': 'OP_DUP OP_HASH160 
071e31b8289aa9d80b970230cb1b8b76466f2ec4 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG', 
'hex': '76a914071e31b8289aa9d80b970230cb1b8b76466f2ec488ac', 'reqSigs': 
1, 
'type': 'pubkeyhash', 'addresses': 
['1eduGsrvBJcfyTMij2rYXk9viiVV78PNq']}}]
```

---

this is from the documentation:

```
"vout" : [ (array of json objects) 
{ 
"value" : x.xxx, (numeric) The value in BTC 
"n" : n, (numeric) index 
"scriptPubKey" : { (json object) 
"asm" : "asm", (string) the asm 
"hex" : "hex", (string) the hex 
"reqSigs" : n, (numeric) The required sigs 
"type" : "pubkeyhash", (string) The type, eg 
'pubkeyhash' 
"addresses" : [ (json array of string) 
"address" (string) bitcoin address 
,... 
] 
} 
} 
,... 
],
```

---

So basically; I need to access the 'address' value in order to use it as input in an iteration for a different function.

Many thanks for any potential tips and let me know if I need to add additional information or clarify anything:)